# Setting absolute size of facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm creating several facetted plots for a report. The number of facets varies between 2 and 8. Ideally, I'd like the absolute size of each facet (across plots) to be the same (e.g. 4x4 cm) so that it is easier to compare them (and it looks nicer, too).

Is that possible?

```
df1 <- structure(list(group1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("S1", "S2"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), value = 1:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("group1", "group", "value"))

df2 <- structure(list(group1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S1", "S2"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), value = 13:20), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("group1", "group", "value"))

library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(df1) + geom_histogram(aes(x=value)) + facet_wrap(~group)
plot2 <- ggplot(df2) + geom_histogram(aes(x=value)) + facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: check out [`ggh4x::force_panelsizes`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#panel-sizes) and [`ggh4x::facet_manual`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#manual-facets)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've used the following function for this purpose,

```
set_panel_size <- function(p=NULL, g=ggplotGrob(p), file=NULL, 
                           margin = unit(1,"mm"),
                           width=unit(4, "cm"), 
                           height=unit(4, "cm")){

  panels <- grep("panel", g$layout$name)
  panel_index_w<- unique(g$layout$l[panels])
  panel_index_h<- unique(g$layout$t[panels])
  nw <- length(panel_index_w)
  nh <- length(panel_index_h)

if(getRversion() < "3.3.0"){

   # the following conversion is necessary
   # because there is no `[<-`.unit method
   # so promoting to unit.list allows standard list indexing
   g$widths <- grid:::unit.list(g$widths)
   g$heights <- grid:::unit.list(g$heights)

   g$widths[panel_index_w] <-  rep(list(width),  nw)
   g$heights[panel_index_h] <- rep(list(height), nh)

} else {

   g$widths[panel_index_w] <-  rep(width,  nw)
   g$heights[panel_index_h] <- rep(height, nh)

}

  if(!is.null(file))
    ggsave(file, g, 
           width = grid::convertWidth(sum(g$widths) + margin, 
                                unitTo = "in", valueOnly = TRUE),
           height = grid::convertHeight(sum(g$heights) + margin,  
                                  unitTo = "in", valueOnly = TRUE))

  g
}

g1 <- set_panel_size(plot1)
g2 <- set_panel_size(plot2)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1,g2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though I still do not get how to use this function without receiving an error message. Can you expand your answer by showing how to get the desired result with my example data?

Comment: I just tried this with R Devel, and this line doesn't work for me: `g$widths[panel_index_w] <-  rep(list(width), nw)`. I need to use this one: `g$widths[panel_index_w] <-  rep(grid:::unit.list(width), nw)`.

Comment: To reply to my earlier comment: the line `g$widths[panel_index_w] <- rep(list(width), nw)` should be replaced by `g$widths[panel_index_w] <-  rep(width, nw)`. Then things work.

Comment: `set_panel_size` is also available in @baptiste 's package [egg](https://github.com/baptiste/egg).

Comment: @jan-glx When using `set_panel_size` in a Quarto document, there is info that gets displayed after the plot. How to get only the plot?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie consider asking a new question with a reproducible example. I don't even know what Quarto is. I have seen a similar issue using patchwork in Rmarkdown documents which is a known bug in Rstudio (which somehow messes with print functions to show inline results), If you use RStudio try without Rstudio