# Setting width in gtable object collapses plot; this used to work but it doesn't anymore.

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable, cowplot

The following code used to work but doesn't anymore. Does anybody have an idea what's going on? It must be some change in the underlying gtable code.

```
require(cowplot) # for plot_grid()
require(grid) # for unit_max()

# make two plots
plot.iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ Species) + stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
  background_grid(major = 'y', minor = "none") + 
  panel_border()
plot.mpg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5)

g.iris <- ggplotGrob(plot.iris) # convert to gtable
g.mpg <- ggplotGrob(plot.mpg) # convert to gtable

iris.widths <- g.iris$widths[1:3] # extract the first three widths, 
                                  # corresponding to left margin, y lab, and y axis
mpg.widths <- g.mpg$widths[1:3] # same for mpg plot
max.widths <- unit.pmax(iris.widths, mpg.widths) # calculate maximum widths
g.iris$widths[1:3] <- max.widths # assign max. widths to iris gtable
g.mpg$widths[1:3] <- max.widths # assign max widths to mpg gtable

plot_grid(g.iris, g.mpg, labels = "AUTO", ncol = 1)
```

The resulting plot is the following:
[image]

What it should look like is this (with the y axis lines perfectly aligned vertically):
[image]

The error seems to happen in this line:

```
g.iris$widths[1:3] <- max.widths
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Note that similar solutions have been used for a long time, see e.g. [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13657460/4975218) And the `plot_grid()` function in cowplot uses code like this also to align plots, and it still works. So this has me completely mystified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**
With `grid` version 3.3.0,  this is no longer an issue. That is, the lines of code containing `grid:::unit.list()` below can be deleted.

The issue is to do with the way units are set. Look at `g.iris$widths`. You'll notice that the numerals are there but the units have been dropped. See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032621/element-replacement-in-grid-unit-vector), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580946/setting-absolute-size-of-facets-in-ggplot2/32583612#32583612).  After converting the plots to gtables, you need: `g.iris$widths = grid:::unit.list(g.iris$widths)`

```
require(grid) # for unit_max()
require(cowplot)

# make two plots
plot.iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ Species) + stat_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  background_grid(major = 'y', minor = "none") + 
  panel_border()
plot.mpg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) 

g.iris <- ggplotGrob(plot.iris) # convert to gtable   
g.mpg <- ggplotGrob(plot.mpg) # convert to gtable

g.iris$widths = grid:::unit.list(g.iris$widths)   
g.mpg$widths =  grid:::unit.list(g.mpg$widths)

iris.widths <- g.iris$widths[1:3] # extract the first three widths, 
                                  # corresponding to left margin, y lab, and y axis
mpg.widths <- g.mpg$widths[1:3] # same for mpg plot

max.widths <- unit.pmax(iris.widths, mpg.widths) # calculate maximum widths

g.iris$widths[1:3] <- max.widths # assign max. widths to iris gtable
g.mpg$widths[1:3] <- max.widths # assign max widths to mpg gtable

plot_grid(g.iris, g.mpg, labels = "AUTO", ncol = 1)
```

Comment: indeed, `grid:::unit.list()` has been needed for some time; I forget when I started to notice breakage with ggplot2. This unexported grid function has become almost a requirement to do this kind of plot alignment, which may be problematic in a package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The axis lines issue is a bug in the latest ggplot2 version 2.1.0. It's already fixed in github with submission to CRAN pending.

Comment: I removed references to axis lines.

Comment: To be clear: The axis line bug is in ggplot2 2.1.0. I have fixed cowplot to work around the bug and submitted that to CRAN.

Comment: @baptiste Do you have any idea what can be done so that `grid:::unit.list()` becomes an exported function? If it is so important, it should be available. In fact, I was thinking about writing more helper functions to do these kinds of manipulations, but I'm not sure how to proceed now.

Comment: my personal take nowadays would be to put a copy of this function in my own package (I may do that actually).Thankfully there's nothing low-level / internal about this particular one, so it may be enough. You could also try your luck at reminding the `grid` (/gtable/ggplot2) developer(s) of this issue.

Comment: @baptiste With the latest development version of R, this example should now work without `grid:::unit.list()`: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-March/072434.html

Comment: @ClausWilke   Thanks for tracking that down.