# Assign different theme to different facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to know if by only using ggplot it is possible to assign different themes to different facets.

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358424/ggplot2-how-to-force-the-number-of-facets-with-too-few-plots) where I feel that the solution provided by @baptiste should be the best one.

Using his code I obtained the following plot:

[image]

With this data:

```
                    RIM BlackBerry Pearl Palm Treo 700p Motorola Q Nokia 9300 Sony Ericsson M600i Sidekick3                      id
Compact                                  6.9            5.7        6.7        4.5                 5.1       3.6                 Compact
Quality of display                       7.5            6.3        7.3        5.1                 6.2       3.8      Quality of display
Push email availability                  8.2            7.4        6.4        6.4                 6.0       4.5 Push email availability
Brand image                              8.6            8.5        7.2        6.5                 4.5       3.0             Brand image
Comfortable to call                      7.4            6.9        6.1        4.2                 5.2       3.1     Comfortable to call
High prestige                            7.2            6.9        6.8        5.5                 4.0       1.2           High prestige
```

And this code:

```
data_sub = melt(data_sub)

# Set id as factor
data_sub$id = factor(data_sub$id, levels=unique(data_sub$id))

# Add empty levels to reach 9 levels
levels(data_sub$id) = c(levels(data_sub$id), c((1 + length(unique(data_sub$id))):9))

ggplot(data_sub, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill = "same_for_all") ) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ id, ncol = 3, drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = globals$graphics$color$palette2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid   = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

Is it possible to use a `theme()` that will hide all the element related to the plots 7, 8 and 9, while still returning a ggplot object ?

Comment: What larger problem are you trying to solve? Why not just leave out the drop=FALSE?

Comment: I want to keep them there, which is the reason why I created the "useless" factors 7, 8 and 9. I did that in order to keep that exact same sizee for every graph that I want to display and do so while obtaining a ggplot at the end. Check the link to the other question for further details, especially @baptiste answer.

Comment: My guess is that this is not possible, and a solution with grid.extra is the way to go. Any manipulation of the needed ggplot objects can be done in the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I want to avoid if possible to relie on grid.Extra  it leads to another kind of object that can't be saved with ggsave.

Comment: What's the reason you need ggsave for plot saving? You could use png() or bmp() etc.

Comment: It is part of a bigger project where we try to avoid using png() dev.off(). Moreover I am also curious as to whether it is possible.