# Assign unique width to each row of a facet_grid / facet_wrap plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, r-grid

I'm looking to assign a custom width to each row of a one column, facet-wrapped plot in R. (I know this is entirely non-standard.)

With `grid.arrange` I can assign a unique height to each row of a facet-wrapped like plot with the following snippet:

```
group1 <- seq(1, 10, 2)
group2 <-  seq(1, 20, 3)
x = c(group1, group2)
mydf <- data.frame (X =x , Y = rnorm (length (x),5,1), 
                    groups = c(rep(1, length (group1)), rep(2, length(group2))))

plot1 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()
plot2 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, heights=c(1,2))
```

The code above gives each row of the plot a unique height:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a unique *width* to each row of the plot, rather than assign a unique height to each row. Is that even possible with any ggplot2 extension?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the widths? Do you want to add more plots on each row or is it for visual purposes? One idea might be to add margins to each plot. Something like: `plot1 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point() +theme( plot.margin = unit(c(1,10,1,1), "lines"))` where the `10` in the `plot.margin` would be your right margin and could be thought of as your width.

Comment: Thanks @MikeyMike essentially the goal is to have the x-axes of each facet have n units, where n is the number of observations for that facet. Each unit should be represented by a consistent amount of space, so facets that visualize more observations should have physically longer x-axes. The margin trick may work if I set each facet's width as a function of its length relative to the max length! I'm going to try this...

Comment: @MikeyMike Do you know where one can find documentation on the available units for `plot.margin`? I'm praying there's something along the lines of percent, but fear there won't be.

Comment: In terms of documentation on `plot.margin` unfortunately I don't know off the top of my head. But, if you check out `?grid::unit` you can see the unit documentation. This shows you that you can use the `npc` unit to set the width as a function of the page width. So `npc = 0.5` means that the width will be `0.5` the page width. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I believe something like this would work: `plot1 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point() +theme( plot.margin = unit(c(0.01,0.5,0.01,0.01), "npc"))` where the `0.5` roughly equates to your percent.

Comment: YES! `npc` is exactly what I was searching for (I should have grepped with ?). If you mark your last comment as an answer I'll enthusiastically accept!

Comment: Glad to help out! I've uploaded a slightly more detailed discussion as my answer.

Comment: maybe relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/32583612/471093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible if you use the `plot.margin` functionality in the ggplot `theme()`. You can set each plot width as a percent of the total length of the page by doing:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()+theme( plot.margin = unit(c(0.01,0.5,0.01,0.01), "npc"))
plot2 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()+theme( plot.margin = unit(c(0.01,0.2,0.01,0.01), "npc"))
```

When we use `npc`s as our unit of interest in the `plot.margin` call, we are setting relative to the page width. The `0.5` and `0.2` correspond to the right margin. As `npc` increases, the smaller your plot will get.

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, heights=c(1,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As another option, you can use `nullGrob` (a blank grob that just takes up space) to allocate horizontal space in a given row. For example:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

plot1 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()
plot2 <- ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(plot1, nullGrob(), widths=c(1,1)), 
             plot2, heights=c(1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: or `grid.arrange(p1, p2, layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,2,NA,2), 2))`