# Left align the y labels of separate plots (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several datasets that share the same x axis but whose y axes differs by several orders of magnitude. For this reason the labels in the y axis are of variable size and when plotting with ggplot, the x axes become misaligned. To make my plots comparable, I want all x axes to have equal length in the final plots. This is a fairly simple procedure for which [facetting and grids can be used](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page) ([or other options too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot)). However, this procedure implies aggregating all plots and sending them to the same png or eps file. I have several reasons (which are beyond the scope of the post) to store each plot in its own png. To keep the plots comparable, therefore, I will have to find a way to force them to have the same space between the left border of the image and the line that marks the y axis.

My guess was that "padding" the labels with spaces so they all had the same number of character would fix the problem, but it didn't work out. I have also tried changing point.margin to no avail. Someone knows how to achieve this?

```
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
y1 <- seq(1,100,by=1)
y2 <- seq(1,1000000,by=10000)
x <- seq(1,100,by=1)
data <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)

m1 <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y1)) + geom_line() +
        scale_y_continuous(labels=function(label) str_pad(label,width=20,side="right"))
m11 <- m1 + theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major= element_blank(), panel.grid.minor= element_blank(),axis.line=element_line(colour="black"),axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))
m2 <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y2)) + geom_line() + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels=function(label) str_pad(label,width=20,side="right"))
m21 <- m2 + theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major= element_blank(), panel.grid.minor= element_blank(),axis.line=element_line(colour="black"),axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))

png("m1.png")
  m11
dev.off()
png("m2.png")
  m21
dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]

Edit:
[image: Baptise methods]

Comment: try searching for [`set_panel_size`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580946/setting-absolute-size-of-facets-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @baptiste I tried your suggestion, no success yet. Check the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to adress the problem.

First, convert the ggplot object into gtables.

```
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(m11))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(m21))
```

Then, find the largest width and use it so replace the width in the rest of the plots.

```
maxWidth = unit.pmax(g1$widths[2:3], g2$widths[2:3])
g1$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
g2$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
```

Finally, use grid.draw to print your plot into your png device.

```
png("m1.png")
grid.draw(g1)
dev.off()

png("m2.png")
grid.draw(g2)
dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]